# How to override Magento 2 welcome email upon new customer account creation

Tags: magento2, template, email, overrides

I need to customize default Magento welcome email template which is sending upon new customer account creation in my  custom module. I'm using the following functions for sending welcome email upon successful account creation in the admin end.

```
$customer = $this->_customerFactory->create();
$customer->sendNewAccountEmail();
```

But the default email with no password is sending. I need to send email with new email template with username and link to reset the password with custom texts.

I tried to override customer model using preference and plugin method. but nothing worked. Help to resolve the issue fast.